# How to enable a component behavior inside disabled tab in material-ui?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using tabs from M-ui and I needed to add a switch as a tab.
I didn't want to make the tab clickable so I disabled it but not the switch inside it isn't working either.

Here is my code:

[image: Edit green-surf-zxid3]

Comment: Just to be clear I disabled the tab to not show it as an active tab when we click over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can't click on `disabled` element — and on its children; a workaround would be to ignore the target tab when we set an active tab.

Using the `newValue` argument on the `handleChange`, we can check if it's coming from the tab that we don't want to be active when clicked.

```js
const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
  if (newValue === "4") return; // value is 4? ignore
  setValue(newValue);
};
```

Now clicking on the tab below will not be selected. But we don't want to show the ripple effect when it's clicked, so we'll use pass `true` on `disableRipple` prop.

```js
<Tab
  value="4"
  disableRipple={true}
  component="span"
  label={
    <Switch
      checked={isSwitchOn}
      onChange={(e) => setSwitch(!isSwitchOn)}
      name="toggleType"
    />
  }
/>
```

[image: Edit epic-smoke-viejy]

Comment: after seeing your solution I am feeling stupid. It was right in front of my eyes and I started digging to CSS,lol. Btw, Thanks